# UITableView gap between UITableViewHeader and cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have strange problem with tableViewHeader which I resize on scroll.

After first scroll to top, I have space between tableHeader and cells and after each next scroll, space increasing.

In tableViewHeader custom class, after scrolling I change height and return back, then resetting it, so UITableView will update frame size.

Also I have 0.1f height for first section view, UITableViewController,

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

I double checked that tableViewHeader have right height.

I have tried many solutions, but nothing works for me.

What happens? Who is adding extra space and why?

EDIT: Table delegate and data source methods

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.001;
  }

  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      return 0.001;
  }


  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
    return 1;
  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return [self nameCell];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 60;
    }

    return 0;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0.001f)];
        return view;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.tableView) {
        [_tableHeader didScroll:scrollView.contentOffset];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the UITableViewController class? Or at least the relevant methods for the tableview delegate/datasource? It's kinda difficult to figure it out without the code.

Comment: Yep, just added to question

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

First of all, don't set tableViewHeader in custom class. Do it in controller where tableView inserted.

Second: wrap tableViewHeader set in beginUpdates, endUpdates.

I don't know how "updates" for cells used with tableViewHeader, but it works

Answer (score 0):

i fixed that by putting the header(auto layout) into a wrap view which is a fixed UIView as subview. the gap will be gone.

```
    self.header =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FriendDetailHeaderView"
                                             owner:nil
                                           options:nil][0];
self.header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenWidth/16*9+25);
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenWidth/16*9+25)];
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[aView addSubview:self.header];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = aView;
```

the auto layout tableViewHeader sometimes can not work out. but in my previous project, set the auto layout view to tableView.tableViewHeader it works perfectly